# The weakest sufficient condition for the limit of a sucession to have unique limit?

Tags: general-topology, limits

I know that Hausdorff spaces ($T_{2}$ spaces) have uniqueness of the limits. Is there any weaker condition that implies it?

Comment: @Arthur: There is at least one extensively studied property lying strictly between Hausdorffness and the desired property; see my answer.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328725/if-every-compact-set-is-closed-then-is-the-space-hausdorff for an example of a space which is not Hausdorff but has unique limits.

Comment: However in the presence of first-countability, the conditions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces in which convergent sequences have unique limits are called $US$-spaces. Spaces in which compact sets are closed are called $KC$-spaces. All Hausdorff spaces are $KC$, all $KC$-spaces are $US$, and neither implication is reversible. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453708/12042) I gave an example of a $US$-space that is not $KC$. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461809/kc-spaces-imply-us-spaces-but-vise-versa-is-false) contains another example. The [Alexandroff extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) (non-Hausdorff one-point compactification) $\Bbb Q^*$ of the rationals is a well-known example of a $KC$-space that is not Hausdorff.

The $KC$ property is the most natural one that I’ve seen that lies between Hausdorffness and the $US$ property.